# Count the number of dict elements in Pandas column containing a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
df['likes']
0    {'data': [{'id': '651703178310339', 'name': 'A...
1    {'data': [{'id': '798659570200808', 'name': 'B...
2    {'data': [{'id': '10200132902001105', 'name': ...
3    {'data': [{'id': '10151983313320836', 'name': ...
4                                                  NaN
5    {'data': [{'id': '1551927888235503', 'name': '...
6    {'data': [{'id': '10204089171847031', 'name': ...
7    {'data': [{'id': '399992547089295', 'name': 'В...
8    {'data': [{'id': '10201813292573808', 'name': ...
9                                                  NaN
```

Some cells have several elements `'id'`

```
df['likes'][0]
{'data': [{'id': '651703178310339', 'name': 'A'},
  {'id': '10204089171847031', 'name': 'B'}],
 'paging': {'cursors': {'after': 'MTAyMDQwODkxNzE4NDcwMzEZD',
   'before': 'NjUxNzAzMTc4MzEwMzM5'}}}
```

Some cells have zero. I want to get a new variable

```
df['number']
0 2
1 4
2 3
4 0
```

That contains number of elements `'id'`. `df['likes']` was obtained from dict. I tried to count `'id'`

```
df['likes'].apply(lambda x: x.count('id'))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'count'
```

So I tried like this

```
df['likes'].apply(lambda x: len(x.keys()))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

How to fix it?

I was asked to publish a full set of data, I publish three lines so as not to take up much space

```
`df['likes']`
`0 {'data': [{'id': '651703178310339', 'name': 'A'},
  {'id': '10204089171847031', 'name': 'B'}],
 'paging': {'cursors': {'after': 'MTAyMDQwODkxNzE4NDcwMzEZD',
   'before': 'NjUxNzAzMTc4MzEwMzM5'}}}
1 {'data': [{'id': '798659570200808', 'name': 'C'},
  {'id': '574668895969867', 'name': 'D'},
  {'id': '651703178310339', 'name': 'A'},
  {'id': '1365088683555195', 'name': 'G'}],
 'paging': {'cursors': {'after': 'MTM2NTA4ODY4MzU1NTE5NQZDZD',
   'before': 'Nzk4NjU5NTcwMjAwODA4'}}}
2 NaN`
```

Comment: please post a *full* sample of your data.

Comment: Please post an output of the following command: `df[['likes']].head(10).to_dict('records')` so that we could have a __reproducible__ data set

Comment: @MaxU I published 3 rows - it's a big one. I hope 3 rows will be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
In [120]: df.likes.apply(pd.Series)['data'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).notnull()).sum(1)
Out[120]:
0    2.0
1    4.0
2    0.0
dtype: float64
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [146]: df['count'] = [sum('id' in d for d in x.get('data',[]))
                         if pd.notna(x) else 0
                         for x in df['likes']]

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
                                               likes  count
0  {'data': [{'id': '651703178310339', 'name': 'A...      2
1  {'data': [{'id': '798659570200808', 'name': 'C...      4
2                                                NaN      0
```

Data set:

```
In [137]: df.to_dict('r')
Out[137]:
[{'likes': {'data': [{'id': '651703178310339', 'name': 'A'},
    {'id': '10204089171847031', 'name': 'B'}],
   'paging': {'cursors': {'after': 'MTAyMDQwODkxNzE4NDcwMzEZD',
     'before': 'NjUxNzAzMTc4MzEwMzM5'}}}},
 {'likes': {'data': [{'id': '798659570200808', 'name': 'C'},
    {'id': '574668895969867', 'name': 'D'},
    {'id': '651703178310339', 'name': 'A'},
    {'id': '1365088683555195', 'name': 'G'}],
   'paging': {'cursors': {'after': 'MTM2NTA4ODY4MzU1NTE5NQZDZD',
     'before': 'Nzk4NjU5NTcwMjAwODA4'}}}},
 {'likes': nan}]
```

Comment: Constructing all those Series is quite inefficient when you just throw them away.

Answer (score 1):

This almost works:

```
df['likes'].apply(lambda x: len(x['data']))
```

Note the error:

```
> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

That happens because you have some NaN values (which are represented as float NAN).  So:

```
df['likes'][df['likes'].notnull()].apply(lambda x: len(x['data']))
```

Comment: I think this doesn't produce correct numbers, isn't it?

Comment: @MaxU: I missed the `['data']` part, fixed now.

Comment: @JohnZwinck OP seems to want the `len` of `id` in `x['data']`

Comment: @JohnZwinck, oops, sorry, now it produces correct results... +1